# External list Reading items very slow

Tags: bcs

I am trying to retrieve all the columns from External list from sharepoint 2010. Em using the below code

```
 SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems(query);

   foreach (SPField field in collection[0].Fields)
    {

    }
```

Here `collection[0].Fields` takes so much time. How can I avoid this perofrmance problem? Is there way of faster retrieval of items?

Comment: do you have possibility to use LINQ?

Comment: Yes. I see that the first access to SPListItemCollection object takes lot of time like 10-15 seconds in my case just to retrieve 5 items from list. What can be done to avoid this?

Comment: have you used CAML to get the items collection?

Comment: yes.. I am using CAML to get the collection .
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query ="<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='BdcIdentity'/></IsNotNull></Where>";

SPListItemCollection collection= list.GetItems(query);
 foreach (SPField field in collection[0].Fields) {
               //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(field.Title.ToString());
                   
 }  Here first access to collection[0].Fields is very slow

Comment: You have to include the fields you use in the code in the ViewFields node of the CAML query as FieldRef. Are you specifying RowLimit?

Comment: Actually my requirement is to retrieve all columns from the list. I cannot specify the fields in query since it will be dynamic. I do not know what fields are present in the list. I em not specifieng row limit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3718/discussion-between-sharmila-and-falak-mahmood)

Comment: have you seen my updated response?

Comment: yes.. but even in that method did not improve the performance :(

Comment: @Falak, Em referring to http://sharepoint2010tutorialnew.blogspot.in/2011/12/get-data-from-bcs-external-content-type.html  But here also   IMetadataCatalog catalog = service.GetDatabaseBackedMetadataCatalog(SPServiceContext.Current); takes so much time like 35 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCS is a service application, and hence some WCF service calls will be involved. I don't think so CAML/SPList or LINQ will cause any good to improve performance, especially if external list is big. But to gain a huge performance impact it is best to define either a `SpecificFinder-method` to perform direct SQL-query or to add an Filter to the `Finder-method` to improve performance.

See more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464399.aspx